# calculate worktime except lunch break

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
name type  start    end
1    work   08:30  12:00
2    lunch  12:00  12:30
3    work   12:30  17:30 
4    break  17:30  18:00
```

can use a simple SQL to calculate work hours given start and end times round in .5 hours.
for example start at 08:30 and end at 18:15 the result is 8.5 hours? Thx

Comment: SO is no coding service. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Use SUM, DATEDIFF and WHERE

Comment: 33 questions, no accepts?

Comment: @SalmanA I don't know where are 32 others questions. But for this question, I see no answer could solve OP's problem. OP have `param_start_time` and `param_end_time`, for e.g `10:00` and `13:00`, he want to calculate work time base on his provided table, in this e.g result would be `4.5`. But for now all answers only caculate maximum time one could work, base on OP's provide table, and omit his 2 input parameters, and they all will have the same output 8.5 hours for any input params.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach the OP has asked 33 questions so far without accepting any. Clearly has no idea how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use timediff if you need calculate only time values and sum all times, you should do some conversions like TIME_TO_SEC and SEC_TO_TIME after SUM to get result in time format

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end,start)))) FROM test WHERE type="work"
```

Comment: How does this get an upvote?  These functions do not exist in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi think this query and relevant example can help you :

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   DateValueBegin      DATETIME,
   DateValueEnd      DATETIME,
   TypeTime     varchar(40)
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 1, DATEADD(HOUR,-5,GETDATE()), GETDATE(), 'WORK'
UNION
SELECT 2,  GETDATE(), DATEADD(HOUR,1,GETDATE()), 'LUNCH'
UNION 
SELECT 3, DATEADD(HOUR,1,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOUR,3,GETDATE()), 'WORK'
UNION
SELECT 4, DATEADD(HOUR,3,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOUR,4,GETDATE()), 'BREAK'
UNION
SELECT 5, DATEADD(HOUR,4,GETDATE()), DATEADD(HOUR,7,GETDATE()), 'WORK';

select * from #MyTable


select TypeTime, SUM( DATEDIFF(hour,  DateValueBegin, DateValueEnd)) AS 'TotalHour', SUM( DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  DateValueBegin, DateValueEnd)) AS 'TotalMinutes'
from #MyTable
Group By TypeTime

DROP TABLE  #MyTable
```

But your're miss some more information in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the difference to minutes and add them up:

```
select sum(datediff(minute, start, end)) / 60.0 as hours_working
from t
where type <> 'lunch'
```